# How to Bulk Insert Complex Objects into SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing, io, entity-framework-5, query-optimization

I have a small project that deals with huge I/O data, database insertions and state checking.

I'll explain myself:

I have to read hundreds of text files, located in disk, every day at a specific time, with specific lines format inside, convert those lines into objects, as a data migration task.

Later, I need to store reading in a SQL Server using EF 6, downloaded from Nuget package repository 
recently. But, I have a persistent doubt before coding any solution:

Because in the process I would like to avoid unnecessary queries asking for record existence (to avoid duplicates or maintain them until further elimination), after some batch jobs happened.

I have these ideas:

Insert all the input every time and remove duplicates as a sql or my app scheduled task periodically or check every time when the insertion should occur. Take into account that they're hundreds of records to be checked each time and it will be done daily.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you investigated SSIS?

Comment: Where do I find something related to SSIS?

Comment: You can google it and find tons - google it for your current version of SQL Server - like SQL 2008 R2 SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services). I use SSIS for a weekly import of very large XML files and it works very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually take a 2-step approach.

1. Parse the records in a file into the shape required.
2. Insert theparsed records into a secondary table. This table usally does not
   have the constraints of the 'real table' and has some extra columns
   to hold validation flags.
3. Once uploaded, kick off a stored procedure, that checks the records and annotates them with possible invalidity reasons.

Then you can decide to process all, some or none. You could even set the error records aside for later inspection etc. But mainly, you now have the power of 'set based sql operations' instead of being forced into rbar operations (row-by-agonizing-row).